# None and typeclasses

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit-conversion

I am reading "learning scalaz" blog series (this part: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/a+Yes-No+typeclass.html) and i am trying to implement the truthy class for Option.

Here is the typeclass i came up with, pretty straight forward:

```
implicit def optionCanTruthy[A: CanTruthy]: CanTruthy[Option[A]] = CanTruthy.truthys({
  case None => false
  case Some(x) => x.truthy
})
```

the idea is that if we have a typeclass for A, we can use the above defined typeclass for Option[A] and for `(x:Option[A]).truthy` == true if and only if `x != None` and `x.get.truthy == true`

It seems to work fine for code like this:

```
1.some.truthy assert_=== true
0.some.truthy assert_=== false
none.truthy assert_=== false
```

But when i try to define a following method:

```
def truthyIf[A: CanTruthy](cond: A)(ifyes: => String)(ifno: => String): String = {
  if(cond.truthy) { ifyes } else { ifno }
}
```

it explodes when `cond` argument == None with following compile error:

```
console>:29: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type CanTruthy[Option[Nothing]]
              truthyIf(none)(y)(n) assert_=== n
```

Any ideas how to fix this and why won't this work?

To play around with this code, you can clone this repo: `git@github.com:tomasherman/scalaz.git` (this code is in src/scala/day1.scala)

PS: Feel free to change the question title, im not really sure what the 'name of this problem' is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess here is that the code can't figure out the type of `Option` that it is based on getting just a `None` (hence the `Option[Nothing]`).  Try typing your `None` first so the code you are calling knows more about it before passing it to `truthyIf`.  If it was for a `String`, then my suggestion would be to declare as this:

```
val opt:Option[String] = None
```

Once your code can discern the underlying type, I'm guessing it will stop complaining.

Comment: You are correct, sir. using none[Int] or None: [Option[Int]] worked